# Take string with several " in it as one with shlex.split

Tags: python, string, split

i am trying to split a string like this one `A B C "D" "E"`.
When i split it with shlex.split it gives me the output: `[A,B,C,D,E]`
But i want the string "D" and "E" as one string.
My desired output is like: `[A,B,C,"D" "E"]`

Using like maxsplit paramter like for .split function would work, but as i can see shlex.split does not have such parameter.

Comment: What is your criteria for splitting?

Comment: `shlex.split` merely splits a string the same way a POSIX compliant shell would. `A B C "D" "E"` doesn't split that way in the shell, so it won't for your purpose either. How do you determine that `"D" "E"` is one token?

Comment: I want to split every line in 4 strings. The "" string is the last one. So `"D" "E"` should ba taken as one string, because its the 4th string.